# CMS projects to learn from?

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system

There have been quite a few questions about CMS systems but I wonder if there are any good open-source versions available that support ASP.NET MVC (preferably 2.0) and work well with SQL Server?
I'm not looking for a CMS system to use, although that will probably happen too. I'm looking for a CMS system to learn from! So basically, it should follow the [KISS principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).
Yeah, I know about DotNetNuke. It looks okay but it feels like overkill to me. There should be alternatives, right?

---

And no, I'm not a beginner! My web development skills go back to the time when Internet Explorer was still displaying static pages on a Windows 3.11 system when RAM was still measured in kilobytes and with CompuServe as provider over a 33k6 model phone line. But it never hurts to learn from existing code.

Comment: Uhh.. The first version of Internet Explorer was released for Windows 95, and it never had anything to do with static pages (that's the web servers problem, the browser doesn't care if the pages are static or dynamic, and doesn't know the difference.

Comment: True, but Windows 3.11 also had a web browser. And while you could serve dynamic pages then, most people would not even bother to do so, since there weren't any useful scripting languages like PHP or ASP back then. Those pages had to be written in C or other compiled language, and often those applications were complete web server applications. For static pages, you could just use simple, existing solutions. For dynamic pages, you needed experienced programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are very few CMS systems based on MVC, as the technology is so new.  The only open source one I am aware of is [MyTrip.MVC](http://mytripmvc.codeplex.com/).  It's pretty basic, so doesn't have all the bells and whistles, but seems well put together.

Comment: Definitely looks promising. And indeed, there aren't many CMS systems based upon ASP.NET and MVC. Yes, MVC is new but it seems to me an ideal environment for developing CRM products. Which is why I'm surprised that it takes me some trouble finding them...

Answer (score 1):

as far as whats readily available DNN is the best to go with and although it may seem overkill after a few hours of stepping through code you will see the patterns used and understand the DNN system is not so large as it first seems. Also the core DNN team has their code reviewed and gets much input from Microsoft corp when they want to showcase new features of the .net framework.

other than DNN there is a commercial CMS built in .net called Ektron (AKA CMS400). what a terrible system. i had the misfortune of having to use this at one job and on top of being slow it is terribly buggy as well. it has some good features but i wouldn't recommend learning from it cause the results are lack-luster at best.

good luck

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be a good CMS system. It needs to be useful to learn from. :-) Bad systems are probably more interesting if you want to learn from errors made by others.